# Reverse Strings without using predefined functions

Tags: swift

Pardon me as I am a newbie on this language.

Edit: Is there a way to reverse the position of a array element?

I am trying to create a function that test the given input if its a palindrome or not. I'm trying to avoid using functions using reversed()

```
let word = ["T","E","S","T"]
var temp = [String]()
let index_count = 3

for words in word{
    var text:String = words
    print(text)
    temp.insert(text, atIndex:index_count)
    index_count = index_count - 1
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example input and the output you wish to get?

Comment: word = ["T","E","S","T"] expected output temp = ["T","S","E","T"]

Comment: So you want to swap chars?

Comment: @appzYourLife yes.

Comment: If you just want to reverse a collection, you can use the `reversed()` method.

Comment: And what is the rule for swapping chars? e.g. `Enterprise` what should become?

Comment: @zneak is there any other way side from using the reversed() method?

Comment: Can you provide a rule to determine the expected output String?

Comment: Okay hold up, none of this is making sense. **1)** `word` is actually an `Array<String>`, and not `String`, `words` is a `String` **2)** `index_count` is being mutated despite being a `let` constanty, **3)** Swapping those letters has nothing to do with appending. OP, could you please clarify exactly what you wish to do?

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm trying to create a snippet that tells whether the word is a palindrome or not. I want to reverse the strings without using the reversed() method.

Comment: Ok, so you want a function to check if word is palindrome?

Comment: So please update your question. Right know is impossible to find out what you mean ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach *can* be used to reverse an array. But you have to
insert each element of the original array at the *start position*
of the destination array (moving the other elements to the end):

```
// Swift 2.2:
let word = ["T", "E", "S", "T"]
var reversed = [String]()
for char in word {
    reversed.insert(char, atIndex: 0)
}
print(reversed) // ["T", "S", "E", "T"]

// Swift 3:
let word = ["T", "E", "S", "T"]
var reversed = [String]()
for char in word {
    reversed.insert(char, at: 0)
}
print(reversed) // ["T", "S", "E", "T"]
```

The same can be done on the characters of a string directly:

```
// Swift 2.2:
let word = "TEST"
var reversed = ""
for char in word.characters {
    reversed.insert(char, atIndex: reversed.startIndex)
}
print(reversed) // "TSET"

// Swift 3:
let word = "TEST"
var reversed = ""
for char in word.characters {
    reversed.insert(char, at: reversed.startIndex)
}
print(reversed)
```

Comment: This error shows up for: ERROR at line 4, col 20: incorrect argument label in call (have '_:atIndex:', expected '_:at:')
    reversed.insert(char, atIndex: 0)
                   ^      ~~~~~~~
                          atme.
http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57b4cc908a6856ae58be653a

Comment: @JioM.: My code was Swift 2.2. Updated for Swift 3 now.

Comment: May I ask why atIndex was removed on Swift 3.0?

Comment: @JioM.: It was *renamed* to `insert(_, at:)`. At lot changed with Swift 3. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution, in particular https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func invert() -> String {
        var word = [Character]()
        for char in self {
            word.insert(char, at: 0)
        }
        return String(word)
    }
}
var anadrome = "god"
anadrome.invert()

// "dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```swift
extension String {
    func customReverse() -> String {
        var chars = Array(self)
        let count = chars.count

        for i in 0 ..< count/2 {
            chars.swapAt(i, count - 1 - i)
        }

        return String(chars)
    }
}

let input = "abcdef"
let output = input.customReverse()
print(output)
```

You can try it [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57b4ce1425b042255806a1ab).

Comment: i have updated answer to latest swift

Answer (score 0):

```
func reverse(_ str: String) -> String {

    let arr = Array(str) // turn the string into an array of all of the letters

    let reversed = ""

    for char in arr {

        reversed.insert(char, at: reversed.startIndex)
    }

    return reversed
}
```

To use it:

```
let word = "hola"

let wordReversed = reverse(word)

print(wordReversed) // prints aloh
```

Answer (score -1):

### Solution 1

```
let word = "aabbaa"

let chars = word.characters
let half = chars.count / 2
let leftSide = Array(chars)[0..<half]
let rightSide = Array(chars.reverse())[0..<half]
let palindrome = leftSide == rightSide
```

### Solution 2

```
var palindrome = true
let chars = Array(word.characters)
for i in 0 ..< (chars.count / 2) {
    if chars[i] != chars[chars.count - 1 - i] {
        palindrome = false
        break
    }
}
print(palindrome)
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for reversing:

```
var original : String = "Test"
var reversed : String = ""
var c = original.characters
for _ in 0..<c.count{
    reversed.append(c.popLast()!)
}
```

It simply appends each element of the old string that is popped, starting at the last element and working towards the first

Answer (score -1):

```
 static func reverseString(str : String) {
        var data = Array(str)
        var i = 0// initial
        var j = data.count // final
        //either j or i for while , data.count/2 buz only half we need check
        while j != data.count/2  {
            print("befor i:\(i) j:\(j)" )
            j = j-1 
            data.swapAt(i, j) //  swapAt API avalible only for array in swift
            i = i+1 
        }
        print(String(data))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //Reverse String
    
    let str = "Hello World"
    
    var reverseStr = ""

    for char in Array(str) {
        
        print(char)
        
        reverseStr.insert(char, at: str.startIndex)

    }

    print(reverseStr)
```